# Dbeaver 7.1.5 . Dump database doesn't work

Tags: dbeaver

Linux Ubuntu. I try to dump data base and I see dialog error.

Error executing process Process failed (exit code = 2). See error log. Process failed (exit code = 2). See error log.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh only needs to change connection

```
--host=localhost
```

to

```
--host=127.0.0.1
```